# NGINX Forwarding a request

Tags: nginx

I have an NGINX Server set up, I'd like to take a request and forward it to another application on a TCP port.

Let's say I have the following JSON payload

```
{
 "someKey1": 1234,
 "someKey2": "a string"
}
```

This is sent inside query parameters like the following

```
https://mywebsite.com?payload=%7B%0A%20%22someKey1%22%3A%201234%2C%0A%20%22someKey2%22%3A%20%22a%20string%22%0A%7D
```

Is there a way to forward that JSON payload to TCP port 1234 natively with NGINX?

Additionally, can I do any pre-processing of the above payload prior to it being forwarded to TCP port 1234.  For example, I'd like to covert the above JSON to

```
someKey1=1234,someKey2="a string"
```

And then forward this data to TCP port 1234

I understang I'd have to create some sort of REST endpoint using something like springboot to do this, but I'd really like to try and accomplish the above natively with NGINX if possible.

Comment: Does application on port 1234 talk http or just raw tcp?

Comment: It talks just raw tcp

Answer (score 1):

Nginx's primary purpose is HTTP server/proxy.
It can be scripted via ngx_http_lua_module, but for your task it is much simpler to make an app/microservice that will listen HTTP and forward your custom protocol, or modify your app that listens mentioned port to understand HTTP.

When your endpoint talks HTTP - nginx can then be used for routing:

```
location /some_path/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:1234/;
}
location /some_other_path/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:1235/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NGINX is simple web-server, which accepts HTTP requests and forwards them to configured location (may be application server, or any other web-server), and responds back on HTTP to the requester. Data can't be processed inside NGINX.

You can configure forwarding rules in `default` file under `sites-available` directory in NGINX installation directory.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-nginx-web-server-on-a-virtual-private-server) is the nice tutorial of NGINX configuration which might help you.